# reading specific lines from .txt file

Tags: matlab

I have large text file which has lots of information inside. I need to access only a line which stars with '***'. That line contains 17 numbers with a space between them.

Example of the file is,

```
Msg count = 2629    
max send msg count = 34     
avg send msg count = 10.27  
imbalance send msg count = 3.31     
------------------------------  
max recv msg count = 35     
avg recv msg count = 10.27  
imbalance recv msg count = 3.41

***1.100020 306852 1381937 11045 5398.19 2.05 10465 5398.19 1.94 2629 34 10.27 3.31 35 10.27 3.41 0.000000


[INFO]  +++ Sat Sep 24 15:15:33 2016 
+++ (test.c:816) stat1 end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
infilename = 'nameoffile.txt'; % name of your file
m = memmapfile(infilename);  % load file to memory (and after close it)
instrings  = strsplit(char(m.Data.'),'\n','CollapseDelimiters',true).';

checkstr = '***';
% find all string (their indices) starting with checkstr 
ind = find(strncmpi(instrings,checkstr,length(checkstr)));


if isempty(ind)
   fprintf('\n No strings with %s',checkstr)
else
   % first string with string checkstr
   instrings(ind(1)); 
end
```